# Springmockito stubbing support via XML

Tags: springmockito

I'm trying to use the second example as described on Springockito site:
https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/Home

```
<mockito:mock id="accountService" class="org.kubek2k.account.DefaultAccountService" />
```

But how can I stub the Mock so it returns what I want when one of the Mocks getter methods is called? It doesn't seem possible via XML?

Answer (score 1):

You have to inject mock into your test class (@Autowired or @Inject is the easiest way to do that) and stub it just like a normal Mockito mock .

A modified example from a Springockito web page:

```
@Autowired
private AccountService accountService;

@Test
public void shouldCountInterestForDeposit() {
    // given
    Deposit deposit = new Deposit(12);
    given(accountService.countInterestFor(deposit)).willReturn(1000);
    bank.addDeposit(deposit);

    // when
    bank.endOfTheMonth();

    // then
    (...)
}
```